# Не работает OCSP Stapling для Thawte-сертификатов

Tags: ssl, openssl

Не работает OCSP Stapling для Thawte-сертификатов на Nginx, в чем может быть проблема?

Настроил Nginx для работы с OCSP Stapling.

```
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /ssl/ssl_trusted_certificate.crt;
```

Сертификат ssl_trusted_certificate.crt включает в себя сшитые root.crt и intermediate.crt.

Проверочный запрос показывает, что OCSP Stapling все равно выключен:

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx:443 -tls1 -tlsextdebug -status
```

Результат:

```
OCSP response: no response sent
```

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, в чем может быть дело? Или хотя бы понять, в какую сторону идти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, проблема была не в сертификате и настройках сервера. Чтобы OCSP Stapling заработал оказалось достаточно перейти по паре страниц сайта. При первом запросе сервер все равно будет запрашивать данные с серверов сертификационных центров и только затем переходит на OCSP.